# Automatic Website Deployment with Git and Sbt

Tags: git, sbt

I have a git repository that contains a simple web application.  The web application is run as a typical Scala application (I use unfiltered to be specific).  In other words, I can run the web application in production with "sbt start".

I would like to have an easier way of deploying updates to the web application.  I have been creating an assembly, copying it to the server, manually stopping the old server, and starting a new server instance.

My thought is to have a new remote repository `web` that pushes directly to the production server.  I could then add a `post-receive` hook on the production git repository that kills the old server and starts a new one.

Is this a reasonable set up for automated deployment?  Are there any tools to help do this with `sbt` and `git`?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your solution is good for simple cases. But it scales bad, because when your software become more complicated, you need to change hooks in *imperative* way.

Take a look at one of [Continuous Integration servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Software) ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) are good points to start). Using CI servers allows you to use *declarative* approach, when you just specify the results you need. CI server takes care of most of your tasks: fetching the latest code from the repo, building it, testing, packaging, deploying, sending emails. Also, it will be useful when working with team in parallel branches. Summarizing: CI brings scalability to your build process, when growing complexity of your codebase does not interfere with you deploys.

Answer (score 1):

I usually deploy PHP applications using Git hooks. Basic idea is, that from post-update hook is executed update of second (non-bare) repository and checkout of the new version. After that, update script updates database and sends me an e-mail.

You can use this approach with minimal changes. Clone your repo to build area on web server and make a script, which will:

1. cd to second repository.
2. Reset GIT_DIR environment variable (it says where is your origin repository, but you do not want to use it now).
3. Fetch changes from origin repository (`git fetch origin`).
4. Checkout them (`git checkout --force master && git reset --hard` or something like that, just to make sure it will always succeed).
5. Build your application and deploy.

Then run this script from post-update hook in origin repo. Nothing complex here.

Answer (score 0):

https://rubygems.org/gems/git-runner

It's a ruby gem (you don't need to be using Ruby in your app to utilise this) to perform tasks after pushes to a git repository. You can then write your own classes to perform the deploy tasks that you need (or look at using/modifying the existing git-runner-deploy gem). That might fit your bill, though perhaps you'd feel happier using that if you're already using ruby somewhere in your process?